# Make a preinstalled Play Market android app uninstallable

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that should come preinstalled on devices with root access and updated through a private channel on play market.

Is there a way to make the app uninstallable for the most basic user? I mean disable uninstall button in the play market, allowing updates in the same time. As I said the device is rooted.

Comment: Do you mean non-uninstallable?

Comment: is this your app or an app on your phone?

Comment: this is the app I'm developing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the apk from `/data/app/` to `/system/app/`.  Your wording is a bit confusing.  But that should make it so that it cannot be uninstalled.

Comment: this worked, thanks. however, when the next version will be published on play market, will the app in /system/app/ be updated normally?

Comment: No.  The update applies by installing on /data/app however the app remains uninstallable.  They can only uninstall "updates" to the application.